# How do I get a string from a registered Window message's lParam

Tags: c#, winapi

I am trying to decode a message I get back from qCollector.

http://www.mechtrading.com/developers/QCollectorDeveloperGuide_2.1.htm

In WndProc I appear to receive a message which should have lParam as a string, but it looks like an integer. Perhaps it is a pointer?

I have tried using Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(m.LParam)) (See below) BUT no variation of it gives me a string that is NOT empty.

```
Output:
50483: QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_PORTFOLIO_LIST_REQUEST
50484: QCOLLECTOR_PORTFOLIO_LIST_REQUEST_COMPLETE
50485: QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_DATA_REQUEST
50486: QCOLLECTOR_DATA_REQUEST_COMPLETE
50487: QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_REALTIME_SYMBOL_LIST_REQUEST
50488: QCOLLECTOR_REALTIME_SYMBOL_LIST_REQUEST_COMPLETE
50489: QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_PORTFOLIO_ITEMS_REQUEST
50490: QCOLLECTOR_PORTFOLIO_ITEMS_REQUEST_COMPLETE
50491: QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_REMOVE_REALTIME_SYMBOL_REQUEST
50492: QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_CLEAR_REALTIME_SYMBOLS
50493: QCOLLECTOR_LAST_RECORD_UPDATE
50494: QCOLLECTOR_REGISTER_FOR_LAST_RECORD_UPDATE
50495: QCOLLECTOR_UNREGISTER_FOR_LAST_RECORD_UPDATE
50496: QCOLLECTOR_FILE_UPDATE
50497: QCOLLECTOR_ALL_FILES_UPDATED
50498: QCOLLECTOR_REGISTER_FOR_FILE_UPDATES
50499: QCOLLECTOR_UNREGISTER_FOR_FILE_UPDATES
50501: QCOLLECTOR_DELETE_PORTFOLIO_ITEM

SENT to: 13381044 From: 2438012  2438012
Ans: 1

Message:
HWnd: 2438012
LParam: 49440
WParam: 0
Msg: 50484
String:
```

If you create a simple forms App with a button then use this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ApiMessageTest2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
        private static extern int FindWindow(string sClass, string sWindow);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TestQC();
        }

        int nWinHandle;
        bool msgSent = false;

        List<string> AtomsList = new List<string> {
            "QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_DATA_REQUEST",
            "QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_PORTFOLIO_LIST_REQUEST",
            "QCOLLECTOR_PORTFOLIO_LIST_REQUEST_COMPLETE",
            "QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_PORTFOLIO_ITEMS_REQUEST",
            "QCOLLECTOR_PORTFOLIO_ITEMS_REQUEST_COMPLETE",
            "QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_REALTIME_SYMBOL_LIST_REQUEST",
            "QCOLLECTOR_REALTIME_SYMBOL_LIST_REQUEST_COMPLETE",
            "QCOLLECTOR_DATA_REQUEST_COMPLETE",
            "QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_REMOVE_REALTIME_SYMBOL_REQUEST",
            "QCOLLECTOR_DELETE_PORTFOLIO_ITEM",
            "QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_CLEAR_REALTIME_SYMBOLS",
            "QCOLLECTOR_REGISTER_FOR_FILE_UPDATES",
            "QCOLLECTOR_UNREGISTER_FOR_FILE_UPDATES",
            "QCOLLECTOR_FILE_UPDATE",
            "QCOLLECTOR_ALL_FILES_UPDATED",
            "QCOLLECTOR_REGISTER_FOR_LAST_RECORD_UPDATE",
            "QCOLLECTOR_UNREGISTER_FOR_LAST_RECORD_UPDATE",
            "QCOLLECTOR_LAST_RECORD_UPDATE"};

        Dictionary<string, uint> Atoms = new Dictionary<string, uint>();

        public void RegisterAtoms()
        {
            foreach (var atom in AtomsList)
            {
                Atoms.Add(atom, RegisterWindowMessage(atom));
            }

        }

        public void ShowAtoms()
        {
            var sortedAtoms = Atoms.OrderBy(x => x.Value);

            foreach (var pair in sortedAtoms)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pair.Value.ToString() + ": " + pair.Key);
            }
        }

        public void TestQC()
        {

            RegisterAtoms();
            ShowAtoms();
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

            try
            {
                nWinHandle = FindWindow("QCDataInterfaceWndClass", null);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                throw;
            }

            if (nWinHandle == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Duff");
            }


            msgSent = true;
            int ans = SendMessage((IntPtr)nWinHandle, Atoms["QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_PORTFOLIO_LIST_REQUEST"], IntPtr.Zero, this.Handle);
            Console.WriteLine("SENT to: " + nWinHandle + " From: " + proc.MainWindowHandle + "  " + this.Handle);
            Console.WriteLine("Ans: "+ans);
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (msgSent)
            {

                if (Atoms.ContainsValue((uint)m.Msg) || m.LParam == new IntPtr(nWinHandle))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("HWnd: " + m.HWnd.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("LParam: " + m.LParam.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("WParam: " + m.WParam.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Msg: " + m.Msg.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("String: " + Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(m.LParam));

                }
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which message specifically?

Comment: @IInspectable I will add it to the question

Comment: Yes, it is an integer, an *atom*.  You have to [pinvoke this](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GlobalGetAtomName.html) to get the string associated with it.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you have a simple example of pinvoke use please?

Comment: The simple example is in the link I gave you.  Did you even try it?

Comment: Yes. it wants a ushort but I have an IntPtr - I do not know how to cast/convert

Comment: @HansPassant Do you have a method for IntPrt to ushort conversion please?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation you linked to](http://www.mechtrading.com/developers/QCollectorDeveloperGuide_2.1.htm):

> The QCollector Data Interface relies on Windows messages **and the [Windows Global Atom Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932355.aspx)** to accept commands and exchange information with client programs. **Atoms are references to text strings**, managed by Windows, which can be used by Windows programs to share information.
>
> ...
>
> `QCOLLECTOR_PORTFOLIO_LIST_REQUEST_COMPLETE` - After QCollector saves the portfolio list to a temp file, it will will send this message to the HWnd that requested the portfolio list. **lParam is an Atom holding one string value** which is the full path and file name for the portfolio list file. **QCollector deletes the Atom when SendMessage returns**. On receipt of this message the client application can read the file to get the list of current portfolios in QCollector.
>
> ...
>
> `QCOLLECTOR_PORTFOLIO_ITEMS_REQUEST_COMPLETE` - QCollector sends this message to the window handle that requested the portfolio items list. **lParam is an Atom holding one string value** - the full path and file name for the portfolio item list text file created by QCollector. **QCollector deletes the Atom when SendMessage returns**.
>
> ...
>
> `QCOLLECTOR_REALTIME_SYMBOL_LIST_REQUEST_COMPLETE` - QCollector sends this message to the window handle that requested the list. **lParam is an Atom holding one string value** - the full path and file name for the list text file. **QCollector deletes the Atom when SendMessage returns**. On receipt of this message your application can read the file to get information about all the items in the QCollector timed updates list.

And so on for all of the other messages that your app receives in reply to data requests.

Per MSDN documentation:

[About Atom Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649053(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_String_Atoms):

> String Atoms
>
> When applications pass null-terminated strings to the `GlobalAddAtom`, `AddAtom`, `GlobalFindAtom`, and `FindAtom` functions, they receive string atoms (16-bit integers) in return. String atoms have the following properties:
>
> - The values of string atoms are in the range 0xC000 (MAXINTATOM) through 0xFFFF.
> - Case is not significant in searches for an atom name in an atom table. Also, the entire string must match in a search operation; no substring matching is performed.
> - The string associated with a string atom can be no more than 255 bytes in size. This limitation applies to all atom functions.
> - A reference count is associated with each atom name. The count is incremented each time the atom name is added to the table and decremented each time the atom name is deleted from it. This prevents different users of the same string atom from destroying each other's atom names. When the reference count for an atom name equals zero, the system removes the atom and the atom name from the table.
>
> ...
>
> Atom-Table Queries
>
> An application can determine whether a particular string is already in an atom table by using the `FindAtom` or `GlobalFindAtom` function. These functions search an atom table for the specified string and, if the string is there, return the corresponding atom.
>
> **An application can use the `GetAtomName` or `GlobalGetAtomName` function to retrieve an atom-name string from an atom table, provided the application has the atom corresponding to the string being sought**. Both functions copy the atom-name string of the specified atom to a buffer and return the length of the string that was copied. `GetAtomName` retrieves an atom-name string from a local atom table, and `GlobalGetAtomName` retrieves an atom-name string from the global atom table.

So, in your case, given the atom handles being passed in the `lParam` values, you can use [`GlobalGetAtomName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649063.aspx) to retrieve the string values:

> Retrieves a copy of the character string associated with the specified global atom.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ApiMessageTest2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string sClass, string sWindow);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern uint GlobalGetAtomName(ushort nAtom, StringBuilder lpBuffer, int nSize);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TestQC();
        }

        IntPtr nWinHandle;

        Dictionary<string, uint> CommandMsgs = new Dictionary<string, uint>();
        Dictionary<uint, string> NotificationMsgs = new Dictionary<uint, string>();

        public void RegisterMessages()
        {
            List<string> Commands = new List<string> {
                "QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_DATA_REQUEST",
                "QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_PORTFOLIO_LIST_REQUEST",
                "QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_PORTFOLIO_ITEMS_REQUEST",
                "QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_REALTIME_SYMBOL_LIST_REQUEST",
                "QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_REMOVE_REALTIME_SYMBOL_REQUEST",
                "QCOLLECTOR_DELETE_PORTFOLIO_ITEM",
                "QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_CLEAR_REALTIME_SYMBOLS",
                "QCOLLECTOR_REGISTER_FOR_FILE_UPDATES",
                "QCOLLECTOR_UNREGISTER_FOR_FILE_UPDATES",
                "QCOLLECTOR_REGISTER_FOR_LAST_RECORD_UPDATE",
                "QCOLLECTOR_UNREGISTER_FOR_LAST_RECORD_UPDATE"};

            foreach (var MsgName in Commands)
            {
                uint msg = RegisterWindowMessage(MsgName);
                if (msg != 0)
                    CommandMsgs.Add(MsgName, msg);
            }

            List<string> Notifications = new List<string> {
                "QCOLLECTOR_PORTFOLIO_LIST_REQUEST_COMPLETE",
                "QCOLLECTOR_PORTFOLIO_ITEMS_REQUEST_COMPLETE",
                "QCOLLECTOR_REALTIME_SYMBOL_LIST_REQUEST_COMPLETE",
                "QCOLLECTOR_DATA_REQUEST_COMPLETE",
                "QCOLLECTOR_FILE_UPDATE",
                "QCOLLECTOR_ALL_FILES_UPDATED",
                "QCOLLECTOR_LAST_RECORD_UPDATE"};

            foreach (var MsgName in Notifications)
            {
                uint msg = RegisterWindowMessage(MsgName);
                if (msg != 0)
                    NotificationMsgs.Add(msg, MsgName);
            }
        }

        public void ShowMessages()
        {
            var sortedCommands = CommandMsgs.OrderBy(x => x.Value);

            foreach (var pair in sortedCommands)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key}: {pair.Value}");
            }

            var sortedNotifications = NotificationMsgs.OrderBy(x => x.Key);

            foreach (var pair in sortedNotifications)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Value}: {pair.Key}");
            }
        }

        public void TestQC()
        {    
            RegisterMessages();
            ShowMessages();

            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

            try
            {
                nWinHandle = FindWindow("QCDataInterfaceWndClass", null);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                throw;
            }

            if (nWinHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new Exception("Duff");
            }

            int ans = SendMessage(nWinHandle, CommandMsgs["QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_PORTFOLIO_LIST_REQUEST"], IntPtr.Zero, this.Handle);
            Console.WriteLine($"SENT to: {nWinHandle} From: {proc.MainWindowHandle} {this.Handle}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Ans: {ans}");
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            string MsgName;
            if (NotificationMsgs.TryGetValue((uint)m.Msg, MsgName))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"HWnd: {m.HWnd}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Msg: {m.Msg} ({MsgName})");
                Console.WriteLine($"WParam: {m.WParam}");
                Console.WriteLine($"LParam: {m.LParam}");

                if ((MsgName == "QCOLLECTOR_PORTFOLIO_LIST_REQUEST_COMPLETE") ||
                    (MsgName == "QCOLLECTOR_PORTFOLIO_ITEMS_REQUEST_COMPLETE") ||
                    (MsgName == "QCOLLECTOR_REALTIME_SYMBOL_LIST_REQUEST_COMPLETE") ||
                    (MsgName == "QCOLLECTOR_DATA_REQUEST_COMPLETE") ||
                    (MsgName == "QCOLLECTOR_FILE_UPDATE") ||
                    (MsgName == "QCOLLECTOR_LAST_RECORD_UPDATE"))
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(514);
                    GlobalGetAtomName((ushort)Msg.LParam, sb, sb.Capacity);
                    Console.WriteLine($"String: {sb.ToString()}");    
                }
                else if (MsgName == "QCOLLECTOR_ALL_FILES_UPDATED")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"# Updated: {Msg.LParam}");    
                } 
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```